# Why doesn't this type check?

Tags: haskell

```
class Foo t where
  foo :: t

bar :: Binary t => t -> ()
bar = undefined

repro :: (Binary t, Foo t) => Proxy t -> ()
repro _proxy =
  bar (foo :: t)
```

The compiler complains:

- Could not deduce (Binary t0) arising from a use of ‘bar’
        from the context: (Binary t, Foo t)
          bound by the type signature for:
                     repro :: forall t. (Binary t, Foo t) => Proxy t -> ()
- Could not deduce (Foo t2) arising from a use of ‘foo’
        from the context: (Binary t, Foo t)
          bound by the type signature for:
                     repro :: forall t. (Binary t, Foo t) => Proxy t -> ()

Specifically, I am surprised it does not see I am passing `t` to `bar`, and creates a `t0` type var. `t2` is even more mysterious, because `foo` is explicitly annotated with type `t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type variables, by default, are not scoped that way. The `t` in the function signature and the `t` in the function body are not the same. Your code is equivalent to this:

```
repro :: (Binary t, Foo t) => Proxy t -> ()
repro _proxy =
  bar (foo :: a)
```

You need to enable the ScopedTypeVariables extension, and add an explicit `forall t`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

repro :: forall t. (Binary t, Foo t) => Proxy t -> ()
repro _proxy =
  bar (foo :: t)
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to turn on the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension and then use

```
repro :: forall t. (Binary t, Foo t) => Proxy t -> ()
repro _proxy = bar (foo :: t)
```

Otherwise, the `t` in `foo :: t` is not related to the other `t` in the `repro` signature. Essentially `foo :: t` becomes equivalent to `foo :: forall a. a`.

This is arguably one the most disliked features of the Haskell definition, and `ScopedTypeVariables` is very popular since it allows to work around that. (In my opinion, it should be on by default.)

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, this can also be handled without extensions. The key trick here is to write a function whose type is *more* restricted than it needs to be, to connect the `Proxy`'s type argument with the `Foo` instance. So:

```
-- most general possible type is Foo b => a -> b
fooForProxy :: Foo t => proxy t -> t
fooForProxy _proxy = foo

-- I've changed Proxy to proxy here because that's good practice, but everything
-- works fine with your original signature.
repro :: (Binary t, Foo t) => proxy t -> ()
repro = bar . fooForProxy
```

Of course, the modern way is to use even *more* extensions to eliminate proxies entirely:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

repro :: forall t. (Binary t, Foo t) => ()
repro = bar @t foo
```

Invoking `repro` will again require a type application, as in `repro @Int` or whatever.